# Widget not responding to setOnClickFillInIntent and setPendingIntentTemplate

Tags: android, android-widget

Click event not triggering in android widget in ListView

I have buttons in each row of the listview in a widget and i would like to make them clickable. I am using setPendingIntentTemplate and setOnClickFillInIntent and i was hoping that the onReceive method would be triggered?

```
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_app_widget);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetRemoteViewsService.class);

        rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.drinks_list, intent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.drinks_list, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
```

MyAppWidgetRemoteViewsFactory.java

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    RemoteViews drinks_view = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.drink_row);
    drinks_view.setTextViewText(R.id.drink_name,  drinkItems.get(position).text);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(MyAppWidget.DRINK_UPDATE, position);
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);

    drinks_view.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.minusButton, fillInIntent);

    return drinks_view;
}
```

drink_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/whiteroundcorner"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/minusButton"
            android:backgroundTint="#27A9FF"
            android:text="-"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:minWidth="60dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</RelativeLayout>



public class MyWidgetRemoteViewsService extends RemoteViewsService {
    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new MyAppWidgetRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(),intent);
    }
}


<receiver android:name=".MyAppWidget">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.developer.drinklogger.EXTRA_ITEM" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/my_app_widget_info" />
</receiver>
<service android:name=".MyWidgetRemoteViewsService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"></service>
```

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment. Your `Intent` is targeting `MyWidgetRemoteViewsService`. You mention an `onReceive()` method. Your `PendingIntent` is obtained with `getActivity()`. Which are you trying to trigger, there? A `Service`, a `BroadcastReceiver`, or an `Activity`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have added the MyWidgetRemoteViewsService code. The onReceive being part of the AppWidgetProvider

Comment: OK, that class is actually your `RemoteViewsService`, and you don't really want the clicks to try starting that, so we need to change the class that the `Intent` is targeting. You mention `onReceive()`. Are you trying to get the clicks to trigger your `AppWidgetProvider`?

Comment: Ah, OK, just saw your edit. Change the `.class` in the `Intent` constructor to be your `AppWidgetProvider` subclass, and then change the `PendingIntent` call to `getBroadcast()`, instead of `getActivity()`.

Comment: thanks again! it's crashing when i go to the home screen now "launcher keeps stopping". Ive added my manifest.

Comment: Service is wrong now?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.myapp.myapp.MyAppWidget: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10159 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
0

Comment: Was it crashing before? None of the changes I suggested have anything to do with that crash. Are you explicitly requesting a wake lock in `MyAppWidget`?

Comment: it works when i change constructor value of the intent back to the MyWidgetRemoteViewsService.class again.

Comment: Well, no, it doesn't really work, because that `Intent` is wrong. That doesn't make much sense, anyway, because that `Intent` shouldn't actually be used until you click something in the widget. You mean it's crashing just by going to the home screen? What's the complete stack trace? What's in your `MyAppWidget` class?

Comment: Ah ok! i created separate intent as you said with AppWidgetProvider subclass. it works! thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Like some others have also pointed out, your "intent" in onUpdate method of AppWidgetProvider is pointing to the WidgetRemoteService class. I think changing that to an Activity might solve your issue.

Also if you want to call RemoteViewsService in future after the app widget has been created, then using the onDataSetChanged method should be useful. You can simply receive an intent in the onReceive method of AppWidgetProvider, call the onUpdate method and trigger the notifyDataSetChanged method. NotifyDataSetChanged triggers the onDataSetChanged method in the RemoteViewsFactory of your widget.